Build Pybind11 example with MSYS2, cmake and mingw : Error only Win32 target is supported
I want to compile and run a simple example with Pybind11.
I have two files example.cpp and CMakeLists.txt in my current directory and I use the MSYS2 MinGW x64 shell.
Here is example.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}

Here is CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(example)

find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
find_package(pybind11 CONFIG)

# pybind11 method:
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)

I have installed pybind11 with the command
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pybind11

Then I run
mkdir buildmingw
cd buildmingw
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"

The ouput of this is:
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/cc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/cc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/c++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python: D:/Software/Python/python.exe (found version "3.11.1") found components: Interpreter Development Development.Module Development.Embed 
-- pybind11::lto disabled (problems with undefined symbols for MinGW for now)
-- pybind11::thin_lto disabled (problems with undefined symbols for MinGW for now)
-- Found pybind11: D:/Software/MSYS2/mingw64/include (found version "2.11.1")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/PythonBindC++/buildmingw3

Lauching now make fails
mingw32-make

The output is then
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example.dir/example.cpp.obj
In file included from D:/Software/Python/include/pyport.h:227,
                 from D:/Software/Python/include/Python.h:38,
                 from /mingw64/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:266,
                 from /mingw64/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                 from /mingw64/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12,
                 from /mingw64/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13,
                 from D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\KadalaSchmittC++\PythonBindC++\example.cpp:1:
/mingw64/include/time.h:12:2: error: #error Only Win32 target is supported!
   12 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!
      |  ^~~~~

I also tried to issue the ming32-make command from the MSYS2 MinGW x86 shell, but get exactly the same error message. (So something with erro in /mingw64/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:266 )
I also just checked whether I have a C++ compiler installed under mingw32 with this command
 pacman -Ss mingw-w64-i686-gcc

which gave the output
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc 13.2.0-6 (mingw-w64-i686-toolchain)
    GNU Compiler Collection (C,C++,OpenMP) for MinGW-w64
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc-ada 13.2.0-6
    GNU Compiler Collection (Ada) for MinGW-w64
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc-fortran 13.2.0-6
    GNU Compiler Collection (Fortran) for MinGW-w64
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc-libgfortran 13.2.0-6
    GNU Compiler Collection (libgfortran) for MinGW-w64
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc-libs 13.2.0-6 [installed: 12.2.0-6]
    GNU Compiler Collection (libraries) for MinGW-w64
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc-lto-dump 13.2.0-6
    Dump link time optimization object files (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc-objc 13.2.0-6
    GNU Compiler Collection (ObjC,Obj-C++) for MinGW-w64

However on packages.msys.org I can only find
mingw-w64-x86_64-pybind11
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pybind11
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-pybind11

I just read about  Different MSYS2 environments and how to pick one, but don't really know how I can compile my Pybind11 project with mingw32
Any help appreciated!

"So something with erro in /mingw64/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:266" -- huh? It's time.h where the error comes from, not from pybind... Are you sure you can't reduce the [mcve] further?

Please show the output from the initial cmake invocation.

I have edited the question and have included the output from cmake!

Please add @username to the comment when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications (and we don't get them for question edits). Your question is answered by What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one? that you linked, read the paragraph starting with WARNING: and the one immediately before it. You installed the wrong gcc, pacman -Rs gcc to remove it and pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc to install the correct one.

Thanks @HolyBlackCat I issued the command pacman -Rs gcc from the MSYS2 MinGW x64 shell and then it just worked fine ( I didn't have to issue the command pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc, because it was already installed )

This is weird, having both packages should be ok. This problem hints at wonky PATH contents. Either you're not building in the msys2 terminal (which automatically sets the correct PATH), or you changed PATH manually in the system settings.
